# transferring model to other software

Tags: modeling

How do I transfer my models to other software. Two different ones specifically. I want to transfer a character from blender to davinci resolve to composite in fusion. Then a house model to transfer to Houdini to blow it up? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your objects or even a whole scene in the FBX format that is often used as a common format between different software. You may need to recreate materials since different render solutions have different setups.

Please refer to the documentation how to import in Resolve and Houdini.

Comment: would the fbx setting be under the output tab somewhere cause i cant find it. Where can i find the documentation of the importing?